# Understanding entities code generated by Spring Roo for GWT

Tags: gwt, jpa, spring-roo, entitymanager

We are working on GWT project generated by `Spring Roo` but we no longer use `Roo` to edit/generate classes. Instead we now write all stuff  manually.

For each server-side entity classe Roo generated quite weird `EntityManager` acquisition code. And having to maintain it, I would like to understand it well, but I don't. Here are snippets from generated entity code:

```
@PersistenceContext
transient EntityManager entityManager;

public static final EntityManager entityManager() {
    EntityManager em = new Scenario().entityManager;
    if (em == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)");
    return em;
}

@Transactional
public void persist() {
    if (entityManager == null)
        entityManager = entityManager();
    entityManager.persist(this);
}

public static List<Scenario> findAllScenarios() {
    List<Scenario> res = entityManager().createQuery(
            "select o from Scenario o order by o.name",
            Scenario.class).getResultList();
    return res;
}

public static Scenario findScenario(Long id) {
    if (id == null)
        return null;
    return entityManager().find(Scenario.class, id);
}
```

My observations and questions:

- Instance methods use `EntityManager` field injected by Spring and that's quite clear. But why is this piece for: `if(entityManager == null) entityManager = entityManager();`? Don't we excpect that `EntityManager` in `em` field should be injected and can't be `null` (or else something is wrong?)
- Static method create new instance of entity and get its `EntityManager` field, why? Couldn't be `EntityManager` cached in static field or something like this?
- Why read methods like `findAllXXX` aren't `@Transictional`? From what I know, according JPA spec, all JPA operations should be done within boundaries of transaction?
- is `if (id == null) return null;` piece in `findXXX` methods really necessary? Shouldn't we rather crash application if we get null as `id` parameter to show that something is wrong?
- Could we rewrite this `EntityManager` acquisition code in more elegant way (e.g. without that weird `new Entity().entityManager` stuff) but wihout breaking it (there are probably some preconditions that need to be kept)?
- Why is `EntityManager` field `transient`? Is that important?

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with you, the code looks very suspicious.

The usual way to use EntityManagers in DAOs and @Transactional with Spring is explained perfectly in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/dao.html and http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html, and I don't see why this should be different for Roo-generated code.